# Using RewriteCond to match only a page or a directory having the same name

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to do a redirect of a file and folder using `.htaccess`. I want to add a `RewriteCond` directive before the `RewriteRule` to match only `example.com/place/sta-ana.html` and `example.com/place/sta-ana` directory. I tried this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^place/sta-ana(\.html|/.*)?
RewriteRule ^place/sta-ana(\.html|/.*)? /place/santa-ana$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

and this:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^place/sta-ana(\.html|/.*)?
RewriteRule ^place/sta-ana(\.html|/.*)? /place/santa-ana$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

but both only work for redirecting `place/sta-ana.html` and not the directory and its files like `place/sta-ana/santiago.html` and `place/sta-ana/santiago/lourdes.html`. How can I get the code(s) above to also redirect the `sta-ana` directory to the `santa-ana` folder:

```
example.com/place/sta-ana.html => example.com/place/santa-ana.html
example.com/place/sta-ana/santiago.html => example.com/place/santa-ana/santiago.html
example.com/place/sta-ana/santiago/lourdes.html => example.com/place/santa-ana/santiago/lourdes.html
```

Comment: Do you want to redirect all files inside `example.com/place/sta-ana/` subdirectory to `/place/santa-ana/$1` ?

Comment: Can you write few examples of source and target URLs? e.g it is not clear what is target URL for `example.com/place/sta-ana.html`

Comment: @anubhava, Yes, in addition to `example.com/place/sta-ana.html` redirecting to `example.com/place/santa-ana.html`, I would also want to redirect all files inside `example.com/place/sta-ana/` subdirectory to `example.com/place/santa-ana/$1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like you don't need a `RewriteCond`. Just this rule will do the job:

```sh
RewriteRule ^place/sta-ana(\.html|/.*)$ /place/santa-ana$1 [L,NC,R=301,NE]
```

Make sure this is your topmost rule and you must clear your browser cache completely before testing this change.

Comment: I have seen [this](https://www.danielmorell.com/images/articles/htaccess_guide/daniel_morell_htaccess_rewrite_ruleset_processing_1.0.png) flowchart from an [online article](https://www.danielmorell.com/guides/htaccess-seo/redirects/introduction-to-redirects#rewrite-basics) that shows a substitution is done even though there is no match. But with a `RewriteCond`, the substitution is skipped if no match is found, which I thought would be more efficient. Kindly enlighten me on this.

Comment: Sorry I have posted hundreds of working answer on mod_rewrite but I'm not sure how `substitution is done even though there is no match`. Did you get a chance to test my answer? Does it not work?